# How to recursively copy directories starting with "abc" on Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, copy, rsync

I have a directory `~/plugins/` and inside there are many sub-directories. If I wanted to create a backup somewhere else of just the sub-directories starting with `abc` could I do that with a one line copy command? I would assume something like this would work (but it doesn't):

```
cp -R ~/plugins/abc* ~/destination/
```

I would rather use a one-line command, if possible, because I would also like to use the same syntax for rsync, and if I have to do something like

```
find ~/plugins/ -type d -name "abc*" -exec cp -R {} ~/destination;
```

then that works fine for the `cp` command but it would mean that I would have to run rsync once for each directory and that just doesn't seem efficient :(

Comment: Why does it not work for you? I tested it and it worked fine. Do you need recursive traversal through subdirectories?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Not sure why what you're trying didn't work (but what is the "copy" command?), but this works on Linux at least:

```
cp -r ~/plugins/abc* ~/destination
```

Comment: i used dos for so many years before switching. that's what the copy command is. I'll try it again and see if it works :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an old trick I still use frequently:

```
 (cd ~/plugins/ && tar cfp - abc/) | (cd ~/destination && tar xfpv -)
```

where the `p` preserves attributes, and  `~/destination` can be anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the output of `find` with `rsync`:

```
# warning: untested
find ~/plugins/ -type d -name "abc*" -print0 | rsync -av --files-from=- --from0 ~/plugins/ ~/destination
```

- the `-print0` in `find`, and `--from0` in `rsync` makes sure that we handle files with spaces correctly
- the `--files-from=-` states that we are reading a list of files from stdin

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# copie un fichier avec l'arbo
#
#
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
my $source = shift;
my $dest = shift;
if( !defined $source){ print "Manque fichier source"; exit(0); }
if( !defined $dest){ print "Manque repertoire dest"; exit(0); }

my $dir = dirname($source);
my $file = basename($source);

my @arbo = split(/\//, $dir);
my $direct  = $dest;
if( !-d $direct ) { mkdir $direct; }
foreach my $d(@arbo) {
        $direct.="/".$d;
        if( !-d $direct ) { mkdir $direct; }
}
copy($source,$direct);
```

## name this code snippet for example copyfile

## TESTED : usage : ./copyfile

Comment: note for english speakers: "arbo" is apparently short for "arborescence" (aka "tree structure")